# CONVERT() causing syntax error in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL 5.6 to query my database. There is a column named `funded` that has a `VARCHAR` string that's in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` and I want to convert it into a datetime with the same format during the `SELECT` statement. The problem is, MySQL just keeps spitting back that there is a syntax error:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,funded,103) AS funded
FROM table
```

The error I'm getting:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'funded, 103) AS funded
>   FROM table' at line 1

Anyone spot what I'm doing incorrectly here? I'm following the documentation as closely as I can.

Comment: IIRC `CONVERT` is Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: you are using SQL Server syntax in a mysql query

Comment: So what would be the MySQL equivalent? Can you please submit it in an answer?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel mysql does have a `CONVERT`  function, it just doesn't have a `format` part (so, no `,103`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using SQL Server syntax.  In MySQL, you would do:

```
select str_to_date(funded, '%m/%d/%Y')
```